# Sift-Tree-File for the Vocabulary-tree

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'd like to know if someone has generated a tree-file for the vocab_tree-stack for other descriptors than only calonder. I would like to use it for loop-closing in the RGBD-Slam.
The stack only provides one for calonder-desctiptors, but I'm not really happy with their perfomance, so I'm looking for a way to compare the perfomance of the tree with different descriptors.

Nikolas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12131/sift-tree-file-for-the-vocabulary-tree/) by [NikolasEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/652/nikolasengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nikolas,
in the

https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/perception/objects_of_daily_use_finder/src/odu_finder.cpp

file we have done so for the SIFT feature. Look into the following function:

void ODUFinder::build_database(std::string directory).

D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0